# Deploying Symfony 4 to Heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, symfony4

I have set up a new symfony 4 project that I am trying to deploy on heroku.  I have the app set up and running successfully locally.  I bascially followed the instructions from the [heroku tutorial here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony).  However, this tutorial is only written for symfony versions 2 and 3.

I had set up a symfony 3 app in the past successfully, I had to create a Procfile to direct the heroku server to the `web/` directory, as per the instructions in the "Best Practices" section.  In this S4 installation I don't see a `web/` folder, so I didn't create a Procfile.  Heroku uses a default command in this case.

I have created 2 config vars in `heroku config`: APP_ENV, SYMPHONY_ENV both are set to `prod`.  I deploy the app the heroku, it all deployed successfully, but when I try to access the page, I just get a `403 Forbidden`.  In the logs I get this, which is maybe the correct functionality since I didn't write any code yet:

> [autoindex:error] [pid 116:tid 139699079337728] [client
>   10.5.228.216:17171] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and
>   server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

I don't see an `app` folder, but I do see a folder called `public` with an index file inside.

Does anyone have experience deploying the new version of Symfony 4 to Heroku, if so any tips would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: have you tried it? the public root folder changed from 'web' to 'public' in Symfony 4.

Comment: @LBA i just tried it and thanks for the simple suggestion it seems to have worked, although now I am getting an execption: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\NoConfigurationException in /app/var/cache/prod/srcProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php` Which seems like its OK since I haven't yet configured anything and this heroku server app is set to production

Comment: indeed - so simply continue and ask when you're stuck

Comment: @LBA yes thank you I put in the controller for the base route and the site works, seems silly.  I should have tried earlier what you suggested but somehow it didn't seem obvious.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On Symfony 4 the **web** folder was replaced by **public**. You still need to create the **Procfile** file and add this line:

> web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/

Answer (score 1):

In my case I defined a Procfile with the following content :

```
web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

But it was not enough, I had to install apache-pack with composer :

```
composer require apache-pack (using symfony flex) or composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

(I found the solution on the [heroku-buildpack-php repository](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/issues/278))

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create a `Procfile` in the root of your repository,
with the following content:

> web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/